# Facing error about OwnedIteror attribute error in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, gpu, data-science

I am facing issue with TensorFlow regarding data generator iterator. I want to use sequential model and I created dataframe data generator from data frame. Now I want to train sequential model and I applied this data generator as input to it and now I am facing **Attribute error**.

Is there any way I can resolve this error.

Here is how I used Image generator from Keras:

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
data = datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=dataSet,
    directory=None,
    x_col="x_col",
    y_col='target',
    weight_col=None,
    target_size=(28, 28),
    color_mode="rgb",
    classes=None,
    class_mode="raw",
    batch_size=32,
    shuffle=True,
)
```

Here is my model:

```
model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(28, (3,3), padding='same', input_shape=(32,32,3)))
model.add(keras.layers.Activation('relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(512))
model.add(keras.layers.Activation('relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
```

Here is how I am compiling my model:

```
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
```

I am calling this model:

```
model.fit_generator(generator=data, epochs=10, verbose=1)
```

And my error is:

AttributeError: in user code:

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:576 _reset_compile_cache  *
    self._compiled_trainable_state = self._get_trainable_state()

AttributeError: 'OwnedIterator' object has no attribute '_get_trainable_state'
```

Comment: My guess is that `data` isn't the right thing to pass for the `generator`. But we can't see how you create the `data`, and we can't see the whole error message, so it's impossible to tell. In the mean time, have you read the documentation?

Comment: I can edit question if you want to see data. And generators so you can see how I created data generator. @KarlKnechtel

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I updated question with data generator model. Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong. And also yes I am referring to documentation right now.

Comment: @yashChoksi - were you able to resolve the mentioned error?

Comment: Yes I solved the error. @Prachi

Comment: @yashChoksi Can you share how ?

Comment: I don’t remember how I solved. But I used other approach which creates tensorflow datasets. And it even creates systematic data pipelines. I would say try to use that approach if you can. @Prachi

Comment: But I will let you know if I solve this issue one more time in future.@Prachi

Comment: Okay give me few minutes. Let me find that code. I will post answer in few minutes.@Prachi

Comment: @Prachi so you are getting same error? Or anything other?

Comment: Because I solved this issue.

Comment: Anyway I am posting the whole answer

Comment: Hey @Prachi posted answer. Please check it and let me know if error still persists.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, Apparently mine issue seems to be with the installed libraries version.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After trying so many different image data pipelines I able to solve this answer. Some are getting attribute error and some getting something other.

```
datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator()
data = datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    #Simple dataframe name which contains columns which has path to your image      files and target column with values like 0,1 and many other case.
    dataframe=train,
    # If you gave absolute path in dataframe column then you can put here as None else give directory name and then file names will be accessed from dataframe.
    directory=None,
    # Column name with image names or full absolute paths
    x_col="image_name",
    # Column name with target variables
    y_col="target",
    weight_col=None,
    # If you want to resize your target image with specific size then put it here
    target_size=(32, 32),
    # If converting from rgb to grayscale put here.
    color_mode="rgb",
    classes=None,
    # If you have numpy 1D array of labels which is usually the case then use raw, there are many options given please check docs.
    class_mode="raw",
    batch_size=32,
    shuffle=True
)
```

Now after converting this dataset you can directly feed into keras model.

```
model = keras.models.Sequential()
# Make sure pixel size should remain the same.
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(28, (3,3), padding='same', input_shape=(32,32,3)))
model.add(keras.layers.Activation('relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(512))
model.add(keras.layers.Activation('relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='softmax'))

# Proper loss function is very important because categorical required multiple classes while the problem which I was facing has only 2 classes and it was coded as 0 and 1. So, use of proper loss function is creating different error, such as shape error. 
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss=keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(), metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit_generator(generator=data, epochs=10, verbose=1)
```

Hope this helps.